# Кэширование - дешево и сердито

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Такой вопрос - имеет ли смысл в качестве кэш хранилища использовать текстовый файл?

Comment: подобное кеширование есть смысл использовать, если соблюдаются два условия

 - получение данных с кеша сильно быстрее, чем напрямую
 - скорость получения данных с кеша удоволетворяет пользователя

Comment: Ну вот смотри : если на сайт заходит человек 500 за минуту, и каждому из них надо показать сколько новостей например в базе, то считаем, пишем в текстовых файл и обновляем его каждые например 10 минут.

Comment: если в файл записать готовый кусок html и потом его просто include'ить, то да, может очень сильно ускорить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сайт посещаемый - да имеет.
В типичной ситуации можно сказать, что всегда.

Запросы к БД, парсинг, компоновка даже на самописных быстрых движках занимают время.

Помнится на одном самописе данная хрень позволила отдавать первый проход страницу где-то за 0.05, а последующие за 0.0015. Там было что-то типа Dual Core 2.5 тогда.

Обратный прокси перед сайтом тоже вариант, но его ещё нужно настроить.
А если использовать его для нормальной отдачи не только статики (картинок, стилей, скриптов) но и динамических страниц то строить прокси и CMS прийдется очень тщательно. В типичном случае прокся любо все будет давать из кеша, даже если это не нужно. Либо все будет идти на прямую, так как CMS будет выставлять "Срок годности" задним числом.